# Excel VBA, applying codes in group copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Currently I have a file with already written cells inside. I am tasked to add both something at the start and at the end of said cells and with help, I came up with this code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo ENABLE_EVENTS 'if any error occurs after this line events get enabled.
    
    If Target.Value <> "" And Target.Row > 1 And Target.Column <= 8 And Cells(Target.Row, 13 And 12 And 11).Value <> "" Then
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            Target.Value = Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value & ": " & Target.Value & " [" & Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value & "]"
        Else
            If Cells(Target.Row, 13).Value = "" Then
            Select Case Target.Column
                Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 14
                Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column).Value = ""
                End Select
            End If
    End If

ENABLE_EVENTS:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _
         & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
       MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

This code currently work and I can individually write things and change it accordingly to what I want.

I can copy and paste one cell and it will add the beginning and the end like designed so.

[image]

What I am curious and struggling to achieve, is to copy and paste all of the B column so that every cells change accordingly to the codes. An error occurs if I try like this:

[image]

Is it possible to change multiple things with my line of codes? And possibly target specific columns and rows?

Comment: This part '13 Or 12 Or 11' does not work as you think it does.  It will produce a value that is the bitwise 'OR' of the numbers 13,12 and 11 which is 10. i.e. you have effectively written 'If Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value'.

Comment: I understand, Im going to modify this.